# App Store Connect error IMAGE_TOOL_FAILURE when uploading app screenshots

Tags: ios, image, app-store-connect, screenshot

I am getting this annoying error as I am trying to upload screenshots of my app before submission.

[image]

- The error appears after I upload images for any screen size, and when I try to upload more images for another size.
- It appears in the Version Information screen but also in the media manager.
- It does not matter how long I wait between uploads and does the same with Safari and Firefox.

Has anyone of you seen this and found a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same thing just now.

Comment: Some have started to stick, others not so much. Potential service disruption on Apple's end?

Comment: I am getting the same, let us know if you find any solutions

Comment: Same here too. If someone finds any workaround please share!

Comment: For now I had to manually reupload one by one each error until I had none. Quite tedious, and I couldn't find another way to push my app update

Comment: Facing the same issue. Random screenshots on re-upload showing this error.

Comment: facing with some images, if that image has an error I can't resolve the error even I upload with the new extension.

Comment: Same for me. I "solved" it by uploading the files individually again and again until it worked and survived a page reload.

Comment: I've been doing the same; keep trying to upload, eventually some stick.
I put in a ticket to Apple. Still no response.

Comment: Same issues as everyone here. Super tedious.

Comment: Error message has changed, "an error occurred while uploading this image". But constant retries across all my images *finally* got them all to stick. No satisfaction from Apple as of yet.

Comment: This solution will likely help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73313352/app-store-screenshots-screenshot-uploads-in-progress-error-appscreenshotse

Answer (score 1):

I run into this today, too. 3 out of 7 of my screenshots failed. Consistently and always the same three.

I tried renaming the file and exporting it as a PNG without the alpha channel, but it didn't work.

What worked was going out of the Media Manager page re-uploading the "invalid" screenshots **individually, leaving the Media Manager page before attempting a new upload**.

When I went back to the home page for the app, the screenshot I uploaded didn't show the `IMAGE_TOOL_FAILURE` error. I repeated the process for the other two, again by uploading only one via Media Manager and then going out of that page, and it worked.

Comment: There's also [a post in the Apple forums about this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/648944?login=true&page=2#722558022).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions.
Please try upload all the images at onces.
it sure worked for me.

Comment: it dont work...

Answer (score 0):

For me saving the images as jpg (instead of png) resolved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).